# Charging my US iPad in Israel

Tags: ipad, charging

I brought my iPad charging wire to Israel along with the necessary plug adapter.  I have not been able to charge my iPad. I also tried to charge it off of my wife's MacBook.  No go.  I called the front desk and they said it was a common problem and had me bring my iPad to them for charging.  All of my other electronic devices (SONY camera, Olympus digital dictation device, BlackBerry) are taking the charge as did my wife's MacBook.  Any idea what i need to do differently or wire that I need to buy?

Comment: So they were able to charge it? What did they use?

Comment: I suggest you double-check your brick, that it is a OEM, or at least a good enough knock-off to be dual voltage. I haven't seen 110-only electronics for about 10 years, but you never know. I had no trouble in Israel with a Mac Desktop and several laptops, Apple and otherwise. The Israeli 3-prong pattern is unique. Are you sure your adapter is fitting in well?

Answer (score 1):

Israel has 220v/50Hz power that's standard throughout most of the world, so if there are problems with using an iPad charger to charge, it would most likely be due to substandard local power and not some problem with your equipment.

Even in [high power mode, charging from a MacBook Pro](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4049) is not a good option to charge an iPad unless it's in AirPlane mode with the screen off or powered down entirely so that all the charge can go to the battery.